# Dynamic binding in Java. What are benefits and drawbacks of using Parent as a type and Child as an object?

Tags: java, dynamic-binding

I've read a couple of articles about the static and dynamic binding techniques in Java.

My question is what is the practical difference between

```
Parent a = new Parent();
```

and

```
Parent a = new Child();
```

?

Comment: Not sure if `Parent a = new Child();` will work isn't it supposed to be `Child a = new Parent();`. You can't say car = new Mercerdes, but you can say Mercedes = new car.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer OP may be extends `Parent` class in `Child` class.!!

Comment: @CodeWhisperer you can certainly say `Car car = new Mercedes()` assuming `Mercedes` either `extends` or `implements` `Car`.

Comment: @SamYonnou true just wasn't sure if he made that assumption.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer If `Mercedes` extends `Car` then, `Mercedes = new Car` is totally incorrect and may lead to runtime exception. When you call a method on `Mercedes` (which may not be present in `Car` class) you will get method not found exception but the reverse is always correct i.e, `Car = new Mercedes`  as `Mercedes` will have all properties `Car` has.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer Always a super class reference can refer to a sub-class object but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `Child` object, then second approach doesn't make sense.

Second approach make sense only in case where you want child object but the flexibility to replace `Child` object with `Child2` or Some other `Child` Object which extends `Parent` object transparently at later point of time.

One of the very frequently used example case is `List`, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`. If you want to return List object type but have a flexibility to replace ArrayList with LinkedList (or) LinkedList with ArrayList in your implementation, then you would write code like:

```
List someRefer = new ArrayList();
```

At some point, if your implementation requires lot of inserts/deletes to List, then you realized that LinkedList is best data structure for this case, then you have flexibility to simply change your code to:

```
List someRefer = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: What would be the drawback of writing `ArrayList someRefer = new ArrayList();` and then later changing `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` when required?

Comment: You will get ClassCastException

Answer (score 1):

In the second case where you assign a child object to a parent object, you are allowing the child to act as a parent so that it can interact with other parent objects. In reality, it's still a child with its own fields and methods (overridden or not), but now you can use it like it were a parent object. Put it in an array of parents, compare it to another parent, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The situation created is also known as `runtime polymorphism` which means the `Jvm` will decide whose class members to access at runtime.For ex

```
class Parent {
    public void disp() {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void disp() {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
        Parent p1 = new Child();
        p.disp();

        p1.disp();

    }
}
```

output

```
Parent
Child
```

Means the jvm calls the method on the specified object type.When you used object type to be Child it calls child method and when you call Parent it uses Parent method.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object of Child, Child and Parent have common method suppose display().

```
Parent a = new Child();
a.display();
```

It calls runtime child class method instead of parent class.

**Edit:**

```
public class Parent {

    public void display() {

        System.out.println("Parent-----Display");

    }
}


public class Child extends Parent{

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("This is child method.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent=new Child();
        parent.display();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is child method.
```

Comment: No, `a.display()` uses `Parent`'s method `display()`

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev `a.display()` uses `Parent's` method `display()` compile time.  but run time it uses `Child's` method `display()`